# How can I link DFBP open source with my google spreadsheet to search for a peptide bioactive peptide?

Tags: google-apps-script, open-source

I came from a no code background but i'm trying to link an open source search to my google spreadsheet.

So what i did was, I've tried asking ChatGPT for the guideline and followed all the steps but it doesn't work.

I clicked 'App script' on "Tools" in the top bar menu and paste this code:

```
function openSourceSearch(query) {
  var url = "http://www.cqudfbp.net/proteins/subclass/source_list_display.jsp?SearchNum=2" + encodeURIComponent(query);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var results = data.results;
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    output.push([results[i].title, results[i].url]);
  }
  return output;
}
```

the address on var url is the link of the open source database that I'd like to link.
but it doesn't seem to be working when I tried enter this function on google spreadsheet that I'm working with "=openSourceSearch("my query")"

This was the error that popped out after i used that "=openSourceSearch("my query")".

**[SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', ..."  "... is not valid JSON (line 4).]**

I'm not sure how I can fix this error here. Can someone help me with this matter?

Comment: From your error message, I guessed that your error occurs at `var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());`. In this case, I'm worried that the value of `response.getContentText()` might be invalid data as JSON data. How about confirming it?

Comment: After clicking 'Debug' on the App Script page, yes, you're right. Then do you know how I might fix this error?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `After clicking 'Debug' on the App Script page, yes, you're right.`, I understood that you could understand the reason for your current issue. About your new question of `Then do you know how I might fix this error?`, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I have no information about the API you want to use. So I have no clear answer for resolving your new question. I think that the reason for this is due to my poor experience. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the mapping of "response.getContentText()" as JSON data. You can use below code to map the response as XML instead of JSON data.

```
function openSourceSearch(query) {
    var url = "http://www.cqudfbp.net/proteins/subclass/source_list_display.jsp?SearchNum=2" + encodeURIComponent(query);
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var document = XmlService.parse(response.getContentText());
    var elements = document.getRootElement().getChild("results").getChildren("result");
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       var title = elements[i].getChildText("title");
       var url = elements[i].getChildText("url");
       output.push([title, url]);
    }
    return output;
 }
```

Comment: I've tried your code but the error said: 
[ReferenceError: response is not defined
openSourceSearch @ Code.gs:3]